# Sorting python dictionary based on keys which is alphanumeric values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

I am new to python. In Python, I want to sort list of dictionary items first based on 'year' key and later with key which is alphanumeric ie P1, P2, P3.

**Code snippet is as follows:**

```
[
    {"P9": 0, "year": 2023},
    {"P13": 0, "year": 2023},
    {"P10": 0, "year": 2023},
    {"P11": 121200, "year": 2022},
    {"P12": 0, "year": 2023},
]
```

**Which first sorted by year in acending order becomes:**

```
[
    {"P11": 121200, "year": 2022},
    {"P9": 0, "year": 2023},
    {"P13": 0, "year": 2023},
    {"P10": 0, "year": 2023},
    {"P12": 0, "year": 2023},
]
```

**Again later sorted by period key ie, P1,P2,P3 etc becomes:**

```
[
    {"P11": 121200, "year": 2022},
    {"P9": 0, "year": 2023},
    {"P10": 0, "year": 2023},
    {"P12": 0, "year": 2023},
    {"P13": 0, "year": 2023},
]
```

Above is the expected output,
Now I don't know how do I sort it like this

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: I am only able to sort by year for which i have used below code. 
result_mylist = sorted(mylist, key=itemgetter('year'))
which is giving me this output:
[{'P11': 121200, 'year': 2022}, {'P9': 0, 'year': 2023}, {'P13': 0, 'year': 2023}, {'P10': 0, 'year': 2023}, {'P12': 0, 'year': 2023}]

But now i also want to sort by P1,P2,P3... etc key, which i am not able to do.

Comment: Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72599038/edit) link to update your question with that code you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sorting first base `years` then sorting base first key of each `dict` you can catch number and convert to `int` then sorting like below:

```
>>> sorted(lst_dct, key=lambda x: (x['year'], int(list(x.keys())[0][1:])))
[{'P11': 121200, 'year': 2022},
 {'P9': 0, 'year': 2023},
 {'P10': 0, 'year': 2023},
 {'P12': 0, 'year': 2023},
 {'P13': 0, 'year': 2023}]
```

Comment: This logic is working fine for my code. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

The [sort function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) do all you need

You can pass a key function (a callable) for identifying the correct order.
In your case:

```
unordered = [{'P9': 0, 'year': 2023}, {'P13': 0, 'year': 2023}, {'P10': 0, 'year': 2023}, {'P11': 121200, 'year': 2022}, {'P12': 0, 'year': 2023}]

#by year

sorted(unordered, key=lambda x: x['year'])
# out
[{'P11': 121200, 'year': 2022},
 {'P9': 0, 'year': 2023},
 {'P13': 0, 'year': 2023},
 {'P10': 0, 'year': 2023},
 {'P12': 0, 'year': 2023}]
```

For the period, the solution is a little bit tricky, you must identify how to select the P** key.
We don't know how these dictionaries are built but doing some assumptions
maybe something like:

```
sorted(unordered, key=lambda x: [lbl for lbl in x if lbl.startswith('P')][0] )
```

but here there are lacks of information to be more precise

Answer (score 1):

You can use sorted function, and specify a key function with it. But as you want to use two separate data points as keys, you can use tuple to build a key.

Because when tuples are compared, it first compares the very first entity in it, and if the first one matches, then it goes to check the second entity.

Example:

```
>>> (1,3) > (1, 4)
False

>>> (1, 4) < (2,2)
True

>>> (1, 4, 1) < (2, 1)
True
```

So, here's how you can build your key function:

```
>>> unordered = [{'P9': 0, 'year': 2023}, {'P13': 0, 'year': 2023}, {'P10': 0, 'year': 2023}, {'P11': 121200, 'year': 2022}, {'P12': 0, 'year': 2023}]
>>> ordered = sorted(
    unordered,
    key=lambda d: (d['year'], next(int(k[1:]) for k in d.keys() if k.startswith('P')))
)

>>> ordered
[{'P11': 121200, 'year': 2022}, {'P9': 0, 'year': 2023}, {'P10': 0, 'year': 2023}, {'P12': 0, 'year': 2023}, {'P13': 0, 'year': 2023}]
```

Here, I'm just assuming that you'll always have a key in the dictionary that starts with `P`, and the remaining part of it is an integer.